# MongoDB Filter between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

Simple code for getting documents that have a `creationDate` between two values in mongodb.

If the user provides only one of the values the code should still work and get the documents that have either a `creationDate` less than or bigger than the given value.

I'm mainly looking for more readability and simplicity.

````
interface mongoDateFilter {
  $gte?: Date;
  $lte?: Date;
}

export const getReportsForContent = async (
  contentId: ObjectId,
  beginDate: Date | undefined,
  endDate: Date | undefined,
): Promise<Report[]> => {
  const reportsCollection = await getCollection('reports');

  const creationDateMongoFilter: mongoDateFilter = {};

  if (beginDate) {
    creationDateMongoFilter['$gte'] = beginDate;
  }

  if (endDate) {
    creationDateMongoFilter['$lte'] = endDate;
  }

  let reportsForContent: Report[] = [];

  if (beginDate || endDate) {
    reportsForContent = await reportsCollection.find({ contentId, creationDate: creationDateMongoFilter }).toArray();
  } else {
    reportsForContent = await reportsCollection.find({ contentId }).toArray();
  }

  return reportsForContent;
};
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prefer dot notation over bracket notation** when syntax permits it - it's a bit easier to read and write. ESLint rule: [`dot-notation`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation).

**Construct objects all in one go** rather than mutating them afterwards, if you can - it's easier to write (especially in TypeScript, since you don't have to denote the type ahead of time) and can be easier to understand at a glance when unnecessary mutation is avoided.

**Don't assign expressions that won't be used** - with

```
let reportsForContent: Report[] = [];
```

regardless of the situation, `reportsForContent` will be reassigned to something else afterwards, so you can leave off the `= []` part.

Or, even better:

**Return the value retrieved instead of reassigning a variable and then returning the variable**. This:

```
  if (beginDate || endDate) {
    reportsForContent = await reportsCollection.find({ contentId, creationDate: creationDateMongoFilter }).toArray();
  } else {
    reportsForContent = await reportsCollection.find({ contentId }).toArray();
  }
```

can be

```
  if (beginDate || endDate) {
    return reportsCollection.find({ contentId, creationDate: creationDateMongoFilter }).toArray();
  } else {
    return reportsCollection.find({ contentId }).toArray();
  }
```

Or, even better, handle the case where no date is set at the very beginning, and only construct the `creationDateMongoFilter` later, if it's needed.

**In all:**

```
export const getReportsForContent = async (
    contentId: ObjectId,
    beginDate: Date | undefined,
    endDate: Date | undefined,
): Promise<Report[]> => {
    const reportsCollection = await getCollection('reports');
    if (!beginDate && !endDate) {
        return reportsCollection.find({ contentId }).toArray();
    }
    const creationDateMongoFilter = {
        (...beginDate && { $gte: beginDate }),
        (...endDate && { $lte: endDate }),
    };
    return reportsCollection.find({ contentId, creationDate: creationDateMongoFilter }).toArray();
};
```

No need for the `mongoDateFilter` interface anymore.

Comment: Sending `undefined` to one of `$gte` or `$lte` while the other one is a defined and a date, will not result in the same behavior as supplying only one of `$gte` or `$lte` that's why I had those if statements and conditionally filled the `creationDateMongoFilter` object

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate, that's a surprisingly strict interpretation Mongo has. Tweak is simple enough, you can conditionally add properties to the object during its definition, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704267